# Django : display data got via ajax call on html

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, ajax

I am quite new to django and struggling to do something simple.I'm building map with data visualisation,I am showing the user a simple svg-map  that will help in doing the following:
1-user will click on one of the areas of the map .
2-data visualisation of that specific selected area will be displayed.

First,i send the name of the area( that i got from svg path ) with Jquery,ajax call to python, this is my main.js :

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('path').on('focus', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#selection').html($(this).attr('name'));
      var gov = $('#selection').text();
      console.log(gov)
      var obj = { gov}
      $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '/map/',
          contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', //EDITED
          data: gov,
          success: function(data) {},
          error: function(rs, e) {
          }
      });
    });
  
  });
```

Then, i send the name to python, This is how **my views.py** looks like:

```
[views.py][1]

from django.shortcuts import render
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
# Create your views here.
@csrf_exempt
def map(request):
     if  request.method=='POST':
                data = request.body.decode("utf-8")
                gover=str(data)
                print(gover)
                df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/-/datandvi/main/ndvid.csv', 
                encoding='utf-8',na_values=None)
                d = df[(df['Date'] >= '1984-01-01') & (df['Date'] <= '1985-01-01') & (df['Province'] ==gover )]
                print(d)   
                datadate = d[['Date']].values.tolist()
                dataplot = d[['Data_long_term_Average']].values.tolist()
                def numpy_flat(a):
                        return list(np.array(a).flat)
                k = numpy_flat(dataplot)
                k1 = numpy_flat(datadate) 
                context={ 'gover':gover,'k': k, 'k1': k1 }
                return render(request,'index.html',context)
     else:
                return render(request,'index.html')
```

here

Every time i select on region , the data that i want to display is printed in terminal
data of the selected area is printed but not sent to html page,the context variable is **empty** .
Can you please help ?
[here is my index.html](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ekedYLIzFxyQIoklpd2azXB-_y7R6G7Sq3GPdJ7fR-I/edit?usp=sharing)

--[urls.py](https://docs.google.com/document/d/12oEfrsX0lbguE3W60DNbcNkTx9mcVyRR-7rqjamLYic/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: We can't see any of your Python code, but it sounds like you are using `print` to produce your results.  Instead, you must return your results as a string.

Comment: yes i edit the post now, yes i passed  string value via context like gover but when i inspect the page the value is empty

Comment: Right.  The ONLY thing that gets sent back to the web browser is whatever you `return` from the function.  In this case, that's rendering the `index.html` template.  If you want to send back a JSON result for your Javascript to unpack, you can do that, but you need to return that JSON string from your Python code.  Right now, your AJAX request is just throwing away the result it gets back.

Comment: i passed   data:JSON.stringify(gov), in main.js instead of data:gov,i got string value selected in terminal : "name" but dataframe empty when i passed ...(df['Province'] ==data), also i tried in views gover=json.dumps(data) print(gover) it prints  "\"name\""

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't be able to provide the exact answer unless you add your templates but I can help clean up your code a bit.

Try below and let me know:

main.js

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('path').on('focus', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#selection').html($(this).attr('name'));
    const gov = $('#selection').text();
    console.log(gov)
    let obj = gov
    
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/map/',
        contentType: 'json', // or try deleting this line 
        data: {
            'gov': gov
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log(data.gov);
            console.log(data.k);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log('error', data)
        }
        });
    });
});
```

views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def map(request):
 if  request.method=='POST':
    data = request.POST.get('gov')
    gover=str(data)
    print(gover) #this prints to your command prompt
    df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/-/datandvi/main/ndvid.csv', 
    encoding='utf-8',na_values=None)
    d = df[(df['Date'] >= '1984-01-01') & (df['Date'] <= '1985-01-01') & (df['Province'] ==gover )]
    print(d)   
    datadate = d[['Date']].values.tolist()
    dataplot = d[['Data_long_term_Average']].values.tolist()
    def numpy_flat(a):
            return list(np.array(a).flat)
    k = numpy_flat(dataplot)
    k1 = numpy_flat(datadate) 
    data={ 
        'gover':gover,
        'k': k, 
        'k1': k1 
    }
    return JsonResponse(data, status=200)
return redirect('/index.html/')
```

Comment: when i click on an area in the inspect page  the error is 500 internal server,and urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404 is printed in terminal

Comment: can you add your templates and urls? my answer should only be used as a reference..

Comment: sure ,i added it in my post in the link